# Measure of how much contiguous is a block of pixels

Tags: image-processing, distance, pixel, genetic-algorithm

I'm using `Genetic Algorithms (GA)` on an `image processing` problem (an image segmentation to be more precise). In this case, an `individual` represent a block of pixels (i.e. a set of pixel coordinates). I need to encourage individuals with `contiguous` pixels.

To encourage contiguous blocks of pixels:

- The "contiguousness" of an individual need to be considered in the `fitness function` to encourage `individuals` having adjacent pixels (best-fit). Hence during the evolution, the contiguousness of a set of coordinates (i.e. an individual) will influence the fitness of this individual.

The problem I'm facing is how to measure this feature (how much `contiguous`) on a set of pixel coordinates (x, y)?

As can be shown on the image below, the individual (set of pixels in black) on the right is clearly more "contiguous" (and therefore fitter) than the individual on the left:

Comment: An illustrative example would help this a lot.  At the moment, I doubt that you'll get any substantive response.  Also, please don't tag this with a language when you haven't asked a programming question.

Comment: @Prune I've edited the question, what else do you suggest to add in order to re-open it?

Comment: I suggest that you add more discussion on what you feel defines a group, and what affects contiguity (that's the word you need, I believe).  For instance, consider one set of squares in a diamond ... let's use chess / battleship notation ... a2, b3, b1, c2 -- compared to an arc at a2, c1, c1, d2.  Which is more contiguous?  How far can a pixel be from a cluster's center and still be part of that cluster?  Does the cluster's contiguity affect that range?  What is the "gravity" equation that determines which (or whether) of three competing clusters claims a pixel between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking, and my suggestion would be to count the number of shared "walls" between your pixels:[image: different types of continuity]

I would argue that from left to right the individuals are decreasing in continuity.

Counting the number of walls is not difficult to code, but might be slow the way I've implemented it here.

```
import random

width = 5
height = 5
image = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

num_pts_in_individual = 4

#I realize this may give replicate points
individual = [[int(random.uniform(0,height)),int(random.uniform(0,width))] for x in range(num_pts_in_individual)]

#Fill up the image
for point in individual:
    image[point[0]][point[1]] = 1

#Print out the image
for row in image:
    print row


def count_shared_walls(image):
    num_shared = 0
    height = len(image)
    width = len(image[0])
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):
            if image[h][w] == 1:
                if h > 0 and image[h-1][w] == 1:
                    num_shared += 1
                if w > 0 and image[h][w-1] == 1:
                    num_shared += 1
                if h < height-1 and image[h+1][w] == 1:
                    num_shared += 1
                if w < width-1 and image[h][w+1] == 1:
                    num_shared += 1
    return num_shared

shared_walls = count_shared_walls(image)
print shared_walls
```

Different images and counts of shared walls:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2


[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
0

[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4
```

One major problem with this, is that if a change in pixel locations occurs that does not change the number of shared walls, it will not affect the score. Maybe a combination of the distance method you described and the shared walls approach would be best.

Comment: Could you put the shared walls in a different color (I can see only 4 walls on the first image).

Comment: Sorry, I'm just double counting every wall, since that is easier to code (just divide every count I give by 2). I think that wall counting like this will help distinguish between semi-clustered and tightly-clustered individuals, but won't be of much help if things are far away.